# create csv file java

Tags: java, google-analytics, export-to-csv

Im trying to change the print method to csv instead.

```
    private static void printGaData(GaData results) { 
        System.out.println( 
            "printing results for profile: " + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName()); 

        if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) { 
          System.out.println("No results Found."); 
        } else { 

          // Print column headers. 
          for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) { 
            System.out.printf("%30s", header.getName()); 
          } 
          System.out.println(); 

          // Print actual data. 
          for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) { 
            for (String column : row) { 
              System.out.printf("%30s", column); 
            } 
            System.out.println(); 
          } 

          System.out.println(); 
        } 
      }
```

This method above prints out three columns it works perfect.
So I try to use bufferedwriter to write those three columns to csv by modifying the code to:

```
    private static void ExportGaData(GaData results,PrintWriter pw) {


            System.out.println("printing results for profile: " + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());

            if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
              System.out.println("No results Found.");

              pw.close();

            } else {

              // Print column headers.
              for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
                System.out.printf(header.getName() + " ");
              }
              System.out.println();

            for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
                for (String column : row) {
                  pw.printf("%30s", column,", ");
                    //pw.printf(column + ", ");
                }
                pw.println();

              }

             pw.println();
            }

    }
```

This spit out 1 column instead of 3 columns. The date looks like this:

```
columnA's data    columnb's data    columnC's data
```

all in column A with lots of spaces.How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
for (String column : row) {
       pw.printf(column + ", "); // not row
}
```

Comment: yeah I just realize that, but after I changed it to column, csv was empty, i changed the code then i got three columns data in one column(column A)with spaces. How do I parse it to three columns?T.T...

Comment: pw.printf(column,", ") didnt print anything out,I use  pw.printf("%30s", column,", "),print one column data for all three columns

Comment: You need to close your printwriter

Comment: I put pw.close () after  System.out.println("No results Found."); it doesnt solve the 1 column problem.

Comment: so you problem seems to be that the GaData results passed to printGaData contains data but there is not data in ExportGaData - show us how you are calling this.